# How to get textInput component's selection and number of lines at the same time in React native?

Tags: react-native, textinput

It is possible to get the selection position using onSelectionChange method.

It is also possible to use onLayout method to get the height of TextInput component, which can be used to calculate number of lines.

However, how can I get the selection and number of lines at the same time?

What I am trying to create here is a TextInput component inside a ScrollView. Users would like the ScrollView to scroll to end only when selection end equals the number of lines. However, these two events got shot quite randomly.